# How to add tno-unused-vars errors in @vue/cli

Tags: vuejs2, eslint

In @vue/cli 4.0.5  app I want to add no-unused-vars errors(both in app and in phpstorm )
and I added this option in .eslintrc.js, which contains:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended'
  ],
  rules: {
    'no-console': 'error',
    'no-debugger':  'error',
    "no-unused-vars": "error",
    'no-undef': "error",
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'babel-eslint'
  }
}
```

But I di not see no-unused-vars errors event I restart yarn server.

Are there some other options ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how your configurations are set, but you can always add the eslintConfig on package.json file, like this:

```
"eslintConfig": {
  "root": true,
  "env": {
    "node": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "no-unused-vars": "error"
  }
}
```

Comment: It did not help with .eslintrc.js left unchangable. Have I to remove .eslintrc.js ?

Comment: @mstdmstd according to official eslint documentation, you can just keep the code above in your package.json and delete the file ".eslintrc.js". That will make the "eslintConfig" on package.json default eslint configurator.

Comment: deleting of .eslintrc.js did not help. Checking the project I see a lot package.json inside of node_modules with eslintConfig params. Can I overwrite them all ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't be changing anything inside node_modules; Please upload your project here https://codesandbox.io/ so I can reproduce the code and see what's wrong.